# How to disable the welcome email in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress

**I am looking to prevent Wordpress sending out the Welcome Email to Wordpress Users created using Wordpress Multisite:**

The email looks like this:

Dear User,

Your new account is set up.

You can log in with the following information:
Username: USERNAME
Password: PASSWORD
LOGINLINK

Thanks!

--The Team @ SITE_NAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to wp-content/mu-plugins/ to stop the welcome emails:

```
function db_remove_new_site_notification_email( $blog_id, $user_id, $password, $title, $meta ) {
return false;
}
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_notification', 'db_remove_new_site_notification_email' );
```

More info here: http://danielbachhuber.com/2011/02/15/disable-new-site-creation-email-notifications-for-wordpress-multisite/

*EDIT*

You can shorten this further by using:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_notification', '__return_false' );
```

Hat tip to Chris Haas for pointing that out.

Comment: WordPress has a special function reserved for these cases so you could even shorten this to just `add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_notification', '__return_false' );`

Comment: Sorry David, do you know how to stop these emails coming out to the user as well (not just the admin) - Thanks,